# How to stop page redirection on closing the fancybox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I have following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            beginCartnotification();
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.href = "http://www.someurl.com";
        }, 5000);
    </script>


<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.fancybox({
            'width': '300',
            'height': '90',
            'padding': '40px',
            'autoDimensions': false,
            'border': '1px solid #005195',
            'autoScale': false,
            'transitionIn': 'fade',
            'transitionOut': 'fade',
            'showCloseButton': true,
            'type': 'inline',
            'href': '#cartnotification-popup',
            'onClosed': function(){ //perform some task on closing the fancybox.}
        });
    }
</script>
```

Now what I want to do is if user clicks on the close button on fancy box, page should not redirect.

If user do not click on the close button after 5 seconds user should be redirected to another page.

How can I achieve inside *onClosed* function ?

http://fancybox.net/api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `setTimout` to the `onComplete` property of **fancybox**, which will be called once the content is displayed. If timeout is reached before closing **fancybox**, do your redirect.

In the `onClose` property function clear the timeout, to make sure the `window.loaction` change will not be fired.

Also add the fancybox setup to jQuery's `.ready()` method to make sure initialization takes place as soon as the document is ready.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  beginCartnotification();

  // ADD A VAR TO HOLD YOUR TIMER.
  var timer;

  jQuery.fancybox({
    'width': '300',
    'height': '90',
    'padding': '40px',
    'autoDimensions': false,
    'border': '1px solid #005195',
    'autoScale': false,
    'transitionIn': 'fade',
    'transitionOut': 'fade',
    'showCloseButton': true,
    'type': 'inline',
    'href': '#cartnotification-popup',
    'onComplete': function() {
      timer = setTimeout(function () {
        // REDIRECTING TAKES PLACE AFTER 5 SEC.
        window.location.href = "http://www.someurl.com";
      }, 5000);
    },
    'onClosed': function() {
      // CLEAR THE TIMEOUT !!!
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }
  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Plus one, however I would keep the fancybox initialization script within the `.ready()` method. Also notice you may have a stray closing bracket `}` at the end of your code

Comment: @JFK Absolutely correct. Thx, made an edit to the post.